# How to save a regular expression user input value (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I am making a simple chat bot in Python. It has a text file with regular expressions which help to generate the output. The user input and the bot output are separated by a `|` character.

```
my name is (?P<'name'>\w*) | Hi {'name'}!
```

This works fine for single sets of input and output responses, however I would like the bot to be able to store the regex values the user inputs and then use them again (i.e. give the bot a 'memory'). For example, I would like to have the bot store the value input for 'name', so that I can have this in the rules:

```
my name is (?P<'word'>\w*) | You said your name is {'name'} already!
my name is (?P<'name'>\w*) | Hi {'name'}!
```

Having no value for 'name' yet, the bot will first output 'Hi steve', and once the bot does have this value, the 'word' rule will apply. I'm not sure if this is easily feasible given the way I have structured my program. I have made it so that the text file is made into a dictionary with the key and value separated by the | character, when the user inputs some text, the program compares whether the user input matches the input stored in the dictionary, and prints out the corresponding bot response (there is also an 'else' case if no match is found).

I must need something to happen at the comparing part of the process so that the user's regular expression text is saved and then substituted back into the dictionary somehow. All of my regular expressions have different names associated with them (there are no two instances of 'word', for example...there is 'word', 'word2', etc), I did this as I thought it would make this part of the process easier. I may have structured the thing completely wrong to do this task though.

Edit: code

```
import re

io = {}

with open("rules.txt") as brain:
     for line in brain:
        key, value = line.split('|')
        io[key] = value

string = str(raw_input('> ')).lower()+' word'

x = 1

while x == 1:
    for regex, output in io.items():
        match = re.match(regex, string)
        if match:
            print(output.format(**match.groupdict()))
            string = str(raw_input('> ')).lower()+' word'
    else:
        print ' Sorry?'
        string = str(raw_input('> ')).lower()+' word'
```

Comment: "Talk is cheap. Show me the code." -- Linus Torvalds. See also [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @user1189336 What is the purpose of **' word'** in the expression defining object of name _string_ ?

Comment: @eyquem The purpose of that is to fix a bug whereby if a user did not put another word at the end of their input, the program would default to the 'else' option. However, I now realise it's better to simply make the line split on ' |' instead of '|', since that would also fix the problem I think. (yes that works, derp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some difficulty to understand the principle of your algorithm because I'm not used to employ the named groups.
The following code is the way I would solve your problem, I hope it will give you some ideas.

I think that having only one dictionary isn't a good principle, it increases the complexity of reasoning and of the algorithm. So I based the code on two dictionaries: direg and memory

Theses two dictionaries have keys that are indexes of groups, not all the indexes, only some particular ones, the indexes of the groups being the last in each individual patterns.
Because, for the fun, I decided that the regexes must be able to have several groups.

What I call individual patterns in my code are the following strings:

```
"[mM]y name [Ii][sS] (\w*)"

"[Ii]n repertory (\w*) I [wW][aA][nN][tT] file (\w*)"

"[Ii] [wW][aA][nN][tT] to ([ \w]*)"
```

You see that the second individual pattern has 2 capturing groups: consequently there are 3 individual patterns, but a total of 4 groups in all the individual groups.

So the creation of the dictionaries needs some additional care to take account of the fact that the index of the last matching group ( which I use with help of the attribute of name *lastindex* of a regex MatchObject ) may not correspond to the numbering of individual regexes present in the regex pattern: it's harder to explain than to understand. That's the reason why I count in the function **distr()** the occurences of strings **{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} etc** whose number MUST be the same as the number of groups defined in the corresponding individual pattern.

I found the suggestion of Laurence D'Oliveiro to use '||' instead of '|' as separator interesting.

My code simulates a session in which several inputs are done:

```
import re

regi = ("[mM]y name [Ii][sS] (\w*)"
        "||Hi {0}!"
        "||You said that your name was {0} !!!",

        "[Ii]n repertory (\w*) I [wW][aA][nN][tT] file (\w*)"
        "||OK here's your file {0}\\{1} :"
        "||I already gave you the file {0}\\{1} !",

        "[Ii] [wW][aA][nN][tT] to ([ \w]*)"
        "||OK, I will do {0}"
        "||You already did {0}. Do yo really want again ?")


direg  = {}
memory = {}
def distr(regi,cnt = 0,di = direg,mem = memory,
          regnb = re.compile('{\d+}')):
    for i,el in enumerate(regi,start=1):
        sp = el.split('||')
        cnt += len(regnb.findall(sp[1]))
        di[cnt] = sp[1]
        mem[cnt] = sp[2]
        yield sp[0]

regx = re.compile('|'.join(distr(regi)))
print 'direg :\n',direg
print
print 'memory :\n',memory
for inp in ('I say that my name is Armano the 1st',
            'In repertory ONE I want file SPACE',
            'I want to record music',
            'In repertory ONE I want file SPACE',
            'I say that my name is Armstrong',
            'But my name IS Armstrong now !!!',
            'In repertory TWO I want file EARTH',
            'Now my name is Helena'):

    print '\ninput  ==',inp

    mat = regx.search(inp)
    if direg[mat.lastindex]:
        print 'output ==',direg[mat.lastindex]\
              .format(*(d for d in mat.groups() if d))
        direg[mat.lastindex] = None
        memory[mat.lastindex] = memory[mat.lastindex]\
                                .format(*(d for d in mat.groups() if d))
    else:
        print 'output ==',memory[mat.lastindex]\
              .format(*(d for d in mat.groups() if d))
        if not memory[mat.lastindex].startswith('Sorry'):
            memory[mat.lastindex] = 'Sorry, ' \
                                    + memory[mat.lastindex][0].lower()\
                                    + memory[mat.lastindex][1:]
```

result

```
direg :
{1: 'Hi {0}!', 3: "OK here's your file {0}\\{1} :", 4: 'OK, I will do {0}'}

memory :
{1: 'You said that your name was {0} !!!', 3: 'I already gave you the file {0}\\{1} !', 4: 'You already did {0}. Do yo really want again ?'}

input  == I say that my name is Armano the 1st
output == Hi Armano!

input  == In repertory ONE I want file SPACE
output == OK here's your file ONE\SPACE :

input  == I want to record music
output == OK, I will do record music

input  == In repertory ONE I want file SPACE
output == I already gave you the file ONE\SPACE !

input  == I say that my name is Armstrong
output == You said that your name was Armano !!!

input  == But my name IS Armstrong now !!!
output == Sorry, you said that your name was Armano !!!

input  == In repertory TWO I want file EARTH
output == Sorry, i already gave you the file ONE\SPACE !

input  == Now my name is Helena
output == Sorry, you said that your name was Armano !!!
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this. I am still reading through it and trying to understand it, I'm not very experienced obviously :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, let me see if I understand this:

- You want to a dictionary of key-value pairs. This will be the “memory” of the chatbot.
- You want to apply regular-expression rules to user input. But which rules might apply is conditional on which keys are already present in the memory dictionary: if “name” is not yet defined, then the rule that defines “name” applies; but if it is, then the rule that mentions “word” applies.

Seems to me you need more information attached to your rules. For example, the “word” rule you gave above shouldn’t actually add “word” to the dictionary, otherwise it would only apply once (imagine if the user keeps trying to say “my name is x” more than twice).

Does that give you a bit more idea about how to proceed?

Oh, by the way, I think “|” is a poor choice for a separator character, because it can occur in regular expressions. Not sure what to suggest: how about “||”?

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)
Unfortunately it doesn't help as much as it might have because I theoretically understand what the program ought to do and not to do, ought to save and not to save, but I lack the practical knowledge to make it happen. I think this project is a little ambitious for me actually but its in my free time so I think it's okay.